# Translate VBA function into Dart function

Tags: vba, flutter, dart

I have spent days trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. I am trying to translate a function from VBA to Dart and it appears that I have copied line for line, but I keep getting the wrong answer. Here is the VBA function:

```
Function CND(X As Double) As Double
    Dim y As Double, Exponential As Double, SumA As Double, SumB As Double
    
    y = Abs(X)
    If y > 37 Then
        CND = 0
    Else
        Exponential = Exp(-y ^ 2 / 2)
        If y < 7.07106781186547 Then
            SumA = 3.52624965998911E-02 * y + 0.700383064443688
            SumA = SumA * y + 6.37396220353165
            SumA = SumA * y + 33.912866078383
            SumA = SumA * y + 112.079291497871
            SumA = SumA * y + 221.213596169931
            SumA = SumA * y + 220.206867912376
            SumB = 8.83883476483184E-02 * y + 1.75566716318264
            SumB = SumB * y + 16.064177579207
            SumB = SumB * y + 86.7807322029461
            SumB = SumB * y + 296.564248779674
            SumB = SumB * y + 637.333633378831
            SumB = SumB * y + 793.826512519948
            SumB = SumB * y + 440.413735824752
            CND = Exponential * SumA / SumB
        Else
            SumA = y + 0.65
            SumA = y + 4 / SumA
            SumA = y + 3 / SumA
            SumA = y + 2 / SumA
            SumA = y + 1 / SumA
            CND = Exponential / (SumA * 2.506628274631)
        End If
  End If
  
  If X > 0 Then CND = 1 - CND

End Function
```

Here is the Dart code:

```
double cnd(double X) {
  double y;
  double exponential;
  double sumA;
  double sumB;
  double value;

  y = X.abs();

  if (y > 37) {
    value = 0;
  } else {
    exponential = exp(pow(-y, 2) / 2);
    if (y < 7.07106781186547) {
      sumA = 3.52624965998911E-02 * y + 0.700383064443688;
      sumA = sumA * y + 6.37396220353165;
      sumA = sumA * y + 33.912866078383;
      sumA = sumA * y + 112.079291497871;
      sumA = sumA * y + 221.213596169931;
      sumA = sumA * y + 220.206867912376;
      sumB = 8.83883476483184E-02 * y + 1.75566716318264;
      sumB = sumB * y + 16.064177579207;
      sumB = sumB * y + 86.7807322029461;
      sumB = sumB * y + 296.564248779674;
      sumB = sumB * y + 637.333633378831;
      sumB = sumB * y + 793.826512519948;
      sumB = sumB * y + 440.413735824752;
      value = exponential * sumA / sumB;
    } else {
      sumA = y + 0.65;
      sumA = y + 4 / sumA;
      sumA = y + 3 / sumA;
      sumA = y + 2 / sumA;
      sumA = y + 1 / sumA;
      value = exponential / (sumA * 2.506628274631);
    }
  }
  if (X > 0) {
    value = 1 - value;
  }
  return value;
}
```

In Excel, `=@CND(1)` returns 0.84134475

In Flutter,

```
double cndValue = cnd(1);
print(cndValue);
```

returns 0.5687303062485649. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You were calculating the exponential different from VBA. Please see the code below : [Note - number of decimals returned are different from VBA but answer is as expected by you]

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  print(cnd(1));
}


double cnd(double x) {
  double y, exponential, sumA, sumB;
  double cnds;

  y = x.abs();
  if (y > 37) {
    cnds = 0;
  } else {
    exponential = exp(-y / 2);
    if (y < 7.07106781186547) {
      sumA = 3.52624965998911E-02 * y + 0.700383064443688;
      sumA = sumA * y + 6.37396220353165;
      sumA = sumA * y + 33.912866078383;
      sumA = sumA * y + 112.079291497871;
      sumA = sumA * y + 221.213596169931;
      sumA = sumA * y + 220.206867912376;
      sumB = 8.83883476483184E-02 * y + 1.75566716318264;
      sumB = sumB * y + 16.064177579207;
      sumB = sumB * y + 86.7807322029461;
      sumB = sumB * y + 296.564248779674;
      sumB = sumB * y + 637.333633378831;
      sumB = sumB * y + 793.826512519948;
      sumB = sumB * y + 440.413735824752;
      cnds = exponential * sumA / sumB;
    } else {
      sumA = y + 0.65;
      sumA = y + 4 / sumA;
      sumA = y + 3 / sumA;
      sumA = y + 2 / sumA;
      sumA = y + 1 / sumA;
      cnds = exponential / (sumA * 2.506628274631);
    }
  }
  if (x > 0) cnds = 1 - cnds;
  return cnds;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I inputted the changes and it worked! But cnd(2) returns different results. Why is this?

Comment: No idea, I thought pow() was not required. I'll look into this difference and try to resolve.

Comment: I greatly appreciate the help! I will continue debugging on my end as well.